# Not able to debug C program in eclipse which has scanf() statements

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

On setting the breakpoint on printf in the code below (in eclispe) , during debugging the execution does not stop at scanf to pick up a value for x and instead stop directly only at printf statement. As result cannot enter x during debugging.

```
int main(void) {

    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Entered value of x is : %d \n", x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: could you try adding a `fflush()` ?  seems that the problem is known: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/805830/

Comment: I have already tried it out. It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with optimization, try disabling it (with **gcc** - change `-Ox` to `-O0`).

When optimization is enabled, assembled code generated for consecutive lines of source may be shuffled, so when you try to "Step Into" thru line with `printf`, the cursor position will go back to `scanf`.

Comment: I have done that too. I am using this:
`-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0`

Comment: You may also try this: switch to/open disassembly view, insert breakpoint in first instruction in `main` and restart the program.

Comment: I tried to check "Stop on startup at" option with "main" input in Windows-Preferences->C/C++->GDB
Is that what you meant? ... I tried it and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly. What I meant was that debuggers tend set breakpoint in first instruction after function prologue (where function frame is built). So if your debugger is wrong about where function prologue ends, it might insert the breakpoint in wrong place, causing skipping scanf function. If you insert breakpoint in disassembly view, you can place it exactly where you want and make sure that prologue is not skipped.

Comment: Btw. what architecture and OS are you using?

Comment: Got it. I am on 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Try adding breakpoint at function entry itself. Can be achieved by adding breakpoint at function itself or add breakpoint at caller location and then step thru...